# In Selenium, how do I include a specific node [1] using find_elements_by_css_selector()

Tags: python, selenium, html-parsing

In the case that I want the first use of class so I don't have to guess the find_elements_by_xpath(), what are my options for this? The goal is to write less code, assuring any changes to the source I am scraping can be fixed easily. Is it possible to essentially

```
find_elements_by_css_selector('source[1]')
```

This code does not work as is though.

I am using selenium with Python and will likely be using phantomJS as the webdriver (Firefox for testing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), square brackets select attributes, so your sample code is trying to select the 'source' type element with an attribute named 1, eg

```
<source 1="your_element" />
```

Whereas I gather you're trying to find the first in a list that looks like this:

```
<source>Blah</source>
<source>Rah</source>
```

If you just want the first matching element, you can use the singular form:

```
element = find_element_by_css_selector("source")
```

The form you were using returns a list, so you're also able to get the n-1th element to find the nth instance on the page (Lists index from 0):

```
element = find_elements_by_css_selector("source")[0]
```

Finally, if you want your CSS selectors to be completely explicit in which element they're finding, you can use the [nth-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) selector:

```
element = find_element_by_css_selector("source:nth-of-type(1)")
```

You might find some other helpful information at [this blog post from Sauce Labs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) to help you write flexible selectors to replace your XPath.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of CSS Selectors and have spent some time using them, but was unaware I could use them in this code.

Comment: Btw, this does work in for example Firefox, but for some reason get an out of range in PhantomJS.

Comment: Weeeeeeeird.  With `nth-of-type`?  What's the length of the list of options if you just use find_element_by_css_selector("source")?

Comment: it looks like it can not find the selector. So the site I am scraping must be hiding the selector when using phantom or any headless webdriver?

Comment: That's possible;  Have you inspected the HTML output to see if that's the case with page_source() ?

Comment: I have tried this and get `'unicode' object is not callable` and while using `print driver.current_url` I get `about:blank`. The `.current_url` does work on other sites. One thing I just thought about, this site is an https site, and that could be the issue?